# Как указать часть пути файла в application.properties?

Tags: java, файлы, spring-boot, properties, configuration

Пишу `Spring-MVC` `Rest-api`. Есть метод, который выводит изображения. Путь изображений хранится в БД в строковом виде, а в классе через переменную `String`. Вот ссылка на изображение: `C:\Users\vartanyan\Desktop\images\Orro.jpg`. В приложении используется `Spring-Boot`, `Hibernate` и `PostgreSQL`.
Соответственно, мне необходимо чтобы часть ссылки хранилось в *application.properties*. Например: `C:\Users\vartanyan\Desktop\images\` вот эта часть в *application.properties*, а остальная часть в БД. Я слышал, что так можно делать, но как не знаю.

Метод:

```java
    /**
     * Получить изображение напитка
     *
     * @param response
     * @param drinkId
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public void getDrinkImage(HttpServletResponse response, Long drinkId) throws IOException {

        String imageURL = drinkRepository.getById(drinkId).getImage();

        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(imageURL);
        response.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE);
        IOUtils.copy(in, response.getOutputStream());
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно понял, application.properties пишете

```
upload.path=C:\Users\vartanyan\Desktop\images\
```

А в классе

```
  @Value("${upload.path}")
private String uploadPath;
```

Другую часть сохраняете в bd.

Answer (score 0):

Может будет кому нибудь полезно уточнение к этому решению. В application.properties нужно использовать экранирование path.

```
C:\\Users\\vartanyan\\Desktop\\images
```

Comment: я так указал и сработало: `upload.path=C:/Users/vartanyan/Desktop/images/drinks/`

Comment: У вас прямой слэш... Все дело в направлении слэша... Если брать мой то нужно экранировать... В ответе Николая обратный слэш поэтому я и дал уточнение.